# Notify a service from a PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, service, android-intent, handler, phone-state-listener

I have built an application that listen to call state changes, and I want to notify a service when the call_state became IDLE.

All the components I have are functional, I just need to notify (not start) a service for this.

What's the correct practice, maybe using AIDL?

Because, in a PhoneStateListener, I can't bind to a service. Do I have to start an activity for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think you'd be better off sending your service a broadcast intent than trying to bind to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to notify your service you will need to call though to its process via AIDL.

Comment: But I have to do this from an Activity right?
The fact is that I have a PhoneStateListener listening for call state changes, and when some of this occur I want to notify my service.
Is this possible?

Comment: you would also be able to do this from your listener.

Comment: How? I mean, in a Activity i can wrote:
this.bindService
But I can't in a PhoneStateListener.